# Is it possible to map values in a matrix to colours in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, mapping

I have been trying to get an image from a matrix. Initially I had converted the matrix to a grey-scale image with 5 levels. I want to know if the same thing can be done to make the grey-scale image a colors one, i.e. say I have a value 2.2 and I need it to be in dark blue color, is there any inbuilt function to map values this way and also is it possible to map all the 5 levels to different colours?

Consider the following to be my matrix

```
   x = [ 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.6
         2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
         2.3 2.7 2.5 2.2
         2.6 2.2 2.2 2.2]
```

And I need to map the levels as follows,such that when I convert this into an image , I should be getting the colors in my output image.

```
                 2.2--> Dark blue
                 2.3--> Blue
                 2.4--> Green
                 2.5--> Yellow
                 2.6--> Orange
                 2.7--> Red
```

How do I do it? Please help..Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Reduce your matrix to a set of [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) integers, so that each integer represents one of the original values
2. Show the integer-valued matrix with [`imagesc`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html).
3. Use a custom [`colormap`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) with the desired colors.

This ensures that way each original value, irrespective of their separation, will correspond to a different color.

```
x = [ 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.6
      2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
      2.3 2.7 2.5 2.2
      2.6 2.2 2.2 2.2];                                        % example matrix
colors = [0 0 .6; 0 .6 1; 0 .8 0; 1 .9 0; 1 .5 0; .8 0 0];     % desired colors
[~, ~, xu] = unique(x);                                        % step 1
xu = reshape(xu, size(x));
imagesc(xu)                                                    % step 2
colormap(colors)                                               % step 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`ColorOrder`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html?searchHighlight=ColorOrder) of the axes you plot in and then use `imagesc`. If you don't know in advance how many different values you `x` matrix will have, you have to create your colormap a bit more dynamic than the solution below.

```
% Create your own "colormap"
imgColor = [...
    0 0 0.5; ... % Dark blue
    0 0 1;   ... % Blue
    0 0.8 0; ... % Green
    1 1 0;   ... % Yellow
    1 0.5 0; ... % Orange
    1 0 0    ... % Red
    ];

% Create an axes and set your color order
a = axes;
a.ColorOrder = imgColor;
% Draw image
imagesc(x)
```

[image]

You could also try to play around with the [colormap editor](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html) to change the colors. To open, just type:

```
colormapeditor
```

[image]